# AngularJS ngclick event - cannot navigate from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a beginner to Angular JS. I created a simple login page. After the login process **[Alert is working]** i cannot navigate to the next page. is there any mistake in this code??..  here is my code...

HTML Page

```
 <body ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="Login1ctrl">
   <div class="main">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
     <img src="login.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <label><b>Username</b></label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
     <label><b>Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
       <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
    </div>
   </div>           
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And my Js page..

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', [])
app.controller('Login1ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.submit = function() {
    var uname = $scope.username;
    var password = $scope.password;
    if ($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
        alert($scope.username);
        window.location = '#/dashboard.html';
        /*$location.path('/dashboard.html');*/
    } else {
        alert("UserName & Password is Incorrect");
        /*window.location = '#/login.html';
        $location.path('/login.html');*/
    }
};
}]);
```

Thank you..

Comment: have you defined routing configuration using ngRoute or uiRouter?
You should use `$location.path('/dashboard')` or `$state.go('dashboard')` depending on your routing configuration

Comment: No brother.. routing configuration means??

Comment: try this '#/dashboard' instead of '#/dashboard.html'

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating or https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: You may need to architect your app accordingly to use routing in your application

Comment: @zb22 brother i already tried..

Comment: add $window to controller, like you did with $scope and then try  $window.location.href = '#/dashboard.html';

Comment: @Rahul Thanks Brother I will Try